# WebScrape A Field - Selenium/BeautifulSoup

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, css-selectors

Reposting as question still seems to be outstanding -

A website has a few rows of titles. Some of these titles (**where the titles are blue**), when clicked, expand and show a few more titles. Attached is an example.

**My goal** is to perform a scrape and pull **all** the titles, date, and time. Also if possible, the header for all (an example for line 1 is where it says "On-demand")

**Current code**- has consistency issues and cannot gather all drop down fields.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://cslide.ctimeetingtech.com/esmo2021/attendee/confcal/session/list')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')

new_titles = set()

productlist=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='card item-container session']")
for property in productlist:
    sessiontitle=property.find_element_by_xpath(".//h4[@class='session-title card-title']").text
    print(sessiontitle)
    ifDropdown=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='item-expand-action expand']")
    if(ifDropdown):
        ifDropdown[0].click()
        time.sleep(8)
        open_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-title')
        for open_title in open_titles:
            title = open_title.text
            if(title not in new_titles):
                print(title)
                time.sleep(4)
                new_titles.add(title)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium/Webscrape this field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68473642/selenium-webscrape-this-field)

Comment: another dupe https://stackoverflow.com/a/68476587/7658985

Comment: It does not, it doesnt pull all the date, and time and if possible, the header for all (an example for line 1 is where it says "On-demand") 

I do not know how you did your portion of the code to add this myself - mentioned in post

Answer (score 0):

I have tried pulling the data that you need using `beautifulsoup`.

This prints all the data you need including the **data from the drop-down**.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests


def scrape_sub_lists(s_url):
    resp = requests.get(s_url)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    main_div = soup.find('div', class_='item-content')
    divs = main_div.findAll('div', class_='card presentation')
    print(f'\n***** Sublist Data *****\n')
    for i in divs:
        print(i.find('span', attrs = {'title': 'Session Name'}).text)
        print(i.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip())
        print(i.find('div', class_='details property-auto-width').find('div', class_='property').text)
        print(f'\n\n')
    print(f'\n***** End of Sublist Data *****\n')


url = 'https://cslide.ctimeetingtech.com/esmo2021/attendee/confcal/session/list?p=1'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.findAll('div', class_='card item-container session')
print(len(divs))


for i in divs:
    head = i.find('span', attrs = {'title': 'Location'})
    if head is None:
        head = i.find('span', attrs = {'title': 'Session Type'})
    header = head.text.strip()
    title = i.find('h4', class_='session-title card-title')
    title_name = title.text.strip()
    date = i.find('div', class_='internal_date').find('div', class_='property').text
    time = i.find('div', class_='internal_time').find('div', class_='property').text

    print(f'{header}\n{title_name}\n{date}\n{time}\n\n')

    # Scraping the drop-down data
    a_exists = title.find('a', attrs = {'class': 'item-expand-action expand'})
    if a_exists:
        scrape_sub_lists(a_exists['href'].strip())
```

See the sample output below. The contents between `***** Sublist Data *****` and `***** End of Sublist Data *****` contains the data from the drop-down of the item above it.

```
Sample Output

On-demand
Educational sessions on-demand
Thu, 16.09.2021
08:30 - 09:40


On-demand
Special Symposia on-demand
Thu, 16.09.2021
12:30 - 13:40


On-demand
Multidisciplinary sessions on-demand
Thu, 16.09.2021
16:30 - 17:40


Channel 3
Illumina - Diagnosing Non-Small Cell Lung Cancer using Comprehensive Genomic Profiling
Fri, 17.09.2021
08:45 - 10:15

***** Sublist Data *****

Industry Satellite Symposium
Illumina gives an update on their IVD road map
08:45 - 08:50

Industry Satellite Symposium
The impact of Comprehensive Genomic Profiling
08:50 - 09:01

Industry Satellite Symposium
A day in the life of a pathologist using Comprehensive Genomic Profiling
09:01 - 09:29

Industry Satellite Symposium
Dealing with complexity through Comprehensive Genomic Profiling
09:29 - 09:57

Industry Satellite Symposium
Q & A (Live)
09:57 - 10:15

***** End of Sublist Data *****
```